# Request long/lat precision and request too slow

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geometry, latitude-longitude

I've a PostGIS DB of 18Gb. The tab node (id, tags, geom) is very huge and I need to request long/lat on this table but it's very long when I'm using this sql request :

```
SELECT * FROM nodes WHERE geom = St_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(longitude,latitude),4326)
```

like 300s :/ How can I improve that (i need to do more than 100). And i have another problem with the precision of long/lat because they are note the same (mine and in the Db).

**SOLUTION** : i just need to use the right request !!!

```
SELECT id 
  FROM nodes ORDER BY geom <-> St_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(lng,lat),4326) 
    asc limit 10;
```

for 52M nodes it's take MAX(200ms) !!!

Comment: Do you have indices?

Comment: I find a better way to do that look the Solution !